# gdal for termux(android paython)

Tags: gdal, termux

I am using jupyter notebook for payrhon on my android phone by Termux.
I have a problem with installing "gdal" library.
please help me with proper commands.

Comment: Welcome please describe your problem more clearly and show us what you have done so far, what errors you got etc.

Comment: I have tried this:  "pip install gdal"   then I got this: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-nlshm77k/gdal/

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this:  "pip install gdal"   then I got this: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-nlshm77k/gdal/

Answer (score 0):

"pkg install gdal" worked for me.